# Click event execute funnction

Tags: knockout-2.0

im new to knockoutjs, i cant seem to find any information on how to bind a click event to this element. Could you guys help?

```
<a id="click">Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a data-bind="click:functionClick"> Click here</a>
```

More information can be found here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what i needed! I think i should have done more research.